# Print Management / AIF

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

I have setup the AIF so that when an invoice is created, it gets added to the queue. I know that this doesn't work when Printing to Screen. So I had adjusted the print management settings for that customer to Print to Archive. However, the document still doesn't get added to the AIF queue.

After some investigation, I've found out why. Even though I have "Use Print Management" ticked in the Posting box for posting an Invoice, Under the Printer Setup I have "Send To" set to screen still, when I change this to Print Archive my document gets added to the AIF queue.

So my question is, why is this the case? Why doesn't it pick up what I have set in Print Management for that customer?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to recreate your issue, but it worked for me just as you would have expected. Perhaps your customer print management isn't set up correctly.

To change my test customer's print management settings, I went to the customer in the customer master form, click Setup -> Print management. Expanded Module -> Account -> Documents -> Sales order invoice. Right-clicked on Original  and clicked Override. Then I overrode the default printer destination for that customer.

Follow those steps if you haven't already, and let me know if that works. If not, there may be some other problem.

Comment: If I do that, would I have to do it for every account for that customer? For example when adjusting the Print Management settings usually, you set an Invoice Account to apply those settings for. But when I go to Override, it seems that it will only affect that account and not all accounts associated to it (Invoice Account)?

Comment: I've just repeated your steps and it didn't work. Are you sure you had "screen" selected from printer setup? Interestingly, it DOES also send it to Print Archive as well as whatever is selected in Print Setup, this doesn't make sense to me? It should use only the "Print Management Destination" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are your printers configured as AOS printers?  See `Classes\SalesFormLetter\checkAOSPrintersPrintManagement`

Does this have the same issues in your test environments?  Try resetting your usage data.  There is a `usePrintManagement` variable packed in the invoicing process.

If you can debug this, it should be fairly easy to step through and see if print management is actually getting **used**.

Comment: Hi. We are using AOS Printers yes, I've tried it in my test and UAT environments and I get the same problem. Whenever print to screen is selected it doesn't get added to AIF queue even though I've set a condition for that account in print management to print to archive, which does happen also. So it is picking up the print management setting, it just doesn't add it to the AIF queue if print to screen is also selected under print setup, it should ignore this though I would have thought?